# Inserting a SUM function that references ActiveCell.Offset values (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, loops, sum

I need to enter the sum function into a cell which references ActiveCell.Offset values.  Is there a way to do this in VBA?  Here is the code thus far:

```
 For Each cell In Rec
    If cell.Value = "Y" And cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Y" Then
            cell.Activate
            Selection.Clear
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Clear
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value - (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value + ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value)
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Clear
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Clear
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Clear
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=SUM(ActiveCell.Offset(0,4):ActiveCell.Offset(0,5))"
            Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row & ":S" & ActiveCell.Row).Copy
            pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
            Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row & ":S" & ActiveCell.Row).Delete
End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each cell In Rec
   With cell
       If .Value = "Y" And .Offset(0, 1).Value = "Y" Then
               .Clear
               .Offset(0, 1).Clear
               .Offset(0, 2).Value = .Offset(0, 2).Value - (.Offset(0, 3).Value + .Offset(0, 6).Value)
               .Offset(0, 6).Clear
               .Offset(0, 7).Clear
               .Offset(0, 3).Clear
               .Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=SUM(" & .Offset(0, 4).Resize(, 2).Address(1, 1) & ")"
               ActiveSheet.Range("A" & .row & ":S" & A.row).Copy
               pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
               ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveCell.row & ":S" & ActiveCell.row).Delete
        End If
    End With
Next
```

---

One note you are setting a value in `.Offset(0, 2)` then a few lines later inserting a formula in that same cell.  You may be using the wrong cell reference.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the problem.  It is meant to alter the value of that cell twice, so that part is fine.  I have a follow up question if you might be able to help.  The loop runs through each cell in column G; however, at times, there is a "Y" in consecutive cells (G2 and G3).  So when the loop continues, it will skip over the second consecutive "Y" value.  Are you aware of an easy fix?  I tried to use Offset(-1,0) but the loop continues unaffected.

Comment: Change the loop to a for loop and step -1 so it loops backwards.

Comment: Is there any equivalent to the step -1 within a "for each" loop?  I run into more problems if I reconstruct the entire loop to a "for" loop